# Learning django but i get an error in a simple poll app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn django from scratch. So I found a tutorial online:[Tutorial simple poll app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#) and I followed it and it just replies:

**in the terminal:**

```
Not Found: /polls/
[30/Jan/2021 00:12:39] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1957
```

**On the http://localhost:8000/polls/ web page:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

I went over all the syntax and it all matches up.
please help me I don't know how to solve this probleme

Comment: please share your `urls.py`. most probably you forgot to add the `urlpattern` to point the `urlconf` at `pool.urls` module.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to add polls endpoint to your project's urls.py. Django will start matching URLs from urls.py and then stop at first match if we have included other apps urls then it will search in that apps urls.

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```